# Div that follows you down the page within dynamic boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a form to follow down the page as a viewer scrolls, but stop once reaching the end of the container div (versus continuing into the footer). I got it to work, sort of. It follows me down the page but only a little bit, then stops. I'll place the js, css and html I'm using. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PrZ6.jpg)

```
$().ready(function() {
                var $scrollingDiv = $('#scrollingDiv'); //scrolling div
                var position = $('#endScroll').position(); // div before you want to stop
                var height = $('#page-sidebar').height(); //scrolling div can have dynamic height
                var pos = position.top-(height+5);

                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if($(window).scrollTop() > 200 && $(window).scrollTop() < pos){ //100 is value after it start moving when scrooling
                    $scrollingDiv.stop()
                    .animate({'paddingTop':($(window).scrollTop() - 350) + 'px'}, 'slow');
                }
            });
        });


aside#with-sidebar {
    width:35%;
    float:right;
}




<aside id="with-sidebar">
   <div id="scrollingDiv">
          <form id="form-appointment">...</form>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: Did you try `offset()` instead of `position()`? Try this `var position = $('#endScroll').offset()`

Comment: ok, I tried that and no change - perhaps this video will make it easier to imagine my issue. see how it only goes down a little bit? something is stopping it and I cant put my finger on it. I can't put ANYTHING on it, actually...http://screencast.com/t/VbmEgw8IirF5